# Bootstrap-select issue with Firefox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am having a strange issue with Bootstrap-select and Firefox v.28.

I add values dynamically to an existing selectpicker:

```
$(selector).append($('<option>', { value:name, text:name }));
```

and then call the refresh:

```
$(selector).selectpicker('refresh');
```

It works beautifully on Chrome or Safari. In Firefox v.28, the various items also show on the screen on the side of and below the select control. Wondering if somebody else has seen this behaviour. Thanks in advance...